# Social Engine unable to inspect the html

Tags: php, html, css, social-networking, socialengine

Using Social Engine 4.8.9. 
The site is in development mode. 
If I inspect the html with the chrome inspector I see the html impossible to understand. This is an example:
if I visit the login page, http://localhost/login and I inspect the "email" box I see:

```
<input type="email" name="LpFM0MsRae" id="LpFM0MsRae" value="" class="text" tabindex="1" autofocus="autofocus">
```

In my opinion the html code is obfuscated. Is possible to see the "normal" html code?

Comment: What's obfuscated about that markup for the email box? That's perfectly "normal" html markup. Just because it uses unique random values for the name and id attributes, doesn't mean it's obfuscated

Comment: Ok, I agree. But I want to see the attributes in "human mode". Something like this: <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" tabindex="1" autofocus="autofocus" class="text"> . In the css source code and in php source code I see the correct name. Why in my browser is not in "human mode" ??

Comment: the engine is setting its OWN names. the fact that they're meaningless to you is irrelevant. they're meaningful to the engine, and that's what matters.

Comment: Perhaps because the browser works in "browser mode", not in human mode.... id attribute values should always be unique in a form, and generally you want name attribute values to be unique as well.... but as the only beings reading them are likely to be browsers, then there's no need for them to be human readable.... the argument against making them human readable is that "spambots" look for human readable name/id attributes

Comment: To me is very very relevant becouse I use Selenium web driver to test my application. So I need to configure Selenium to automatic fill the form. Selenium must know which field he must fill. And to do it he must know the css id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked the latest code of 4.8.9 and found the solution for you. Please go to admin>settings->spams and banning tools and disable the Enable anti-spamming technique in login form.

Please feel free to ask your question.